# Reverse engineering numeric patterns

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, reverse-engineering

I'm having a difficult time trying to figure out a general equation or function for some patterns generated using 4 variables `C`, `x`, `y` and `z`. `M` is a 3D matrix of shape `(p, q, C)` containing these values, where `p` and `q` are some large but likely irrelevant integers.

Shown below is a small selection of patterns. Can anyone see what the function `f(C, x, y, z)` might be like? Please note that the values of `C`, `x`, `y` and `z` are not limited to those below, but can be any integers.

```
C = 1
    (x =) 0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
    (y =) 0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8
    (z =) 0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0

   M = [[[0]], [[1]], [[2]], [[3]], [[4]], [[5]], [[6]], [[7]], [[8]], ...]
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (x =) 1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1
    (y =) 0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8
    (z =) 0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0

   M = [[[0]], [[1]], [[2]], [[3]], [[4]], [[5]], [[6]], [[7]], [[8]], ...]
```

---

```
C = 2
    (x =) 0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
    (y =) 0      0      1      1      2      2      3      3      4      4
    (z =) 0      1      0      1      0      1      0      1      0      1

   M = [[[0,     2],   [1,     3]], [[4,     6],   [5,     7]], [[8,    10], ...]
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (x =) 1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1
    (y =) 0      0      1      1      2      2      3      3      4      4
    (z =) 0      1      0      1      0      1      0      1      0      1

   M = [[[0,     4],   [1,     5]], [[2,     6],   [3,     7]], [[8,    12], ...]
```

---

```
C = 3
    (x =) 0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
    (y =) 0      0      0      1      1      1      2      2      2      3      3      3
    (z =) 0      1      2      0      1      2      0      1      2      0      1      2

   M = [[[0,     2,     4],   [1,     3,     5]], [[6,     8,    10],   [7,     9,    11]], ...] 
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (x =) 1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1
    (y =) 0      0      0      1      1      1      2      2      2      3      3      3
    (z =) 0      1      2      0      1      2      0      1      2      0      1      2

   M = [[[0,     4,     8],   [1,     5,     9]], [[2,     6,    10],   [3,     7,    11]], ...]
```

---

```
C = 4
    (x =) 0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
    (y =) 0      0      0      0      1      1      1      1      2      2      2      2      3      3      3      3
    (z =) 0      1      2      3      0      1      2      3      0      1      2      3      0      1      2      3

   M = [[[0,     2,     4,    6],    [1,     3,     5,     7]], [[8,    10,   12,    14],   [9,    11,    13,    15], ...] 
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (x =) 1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1
    (y =) 0      0      0      0      1      1      1      1      2      2      2      2      3      3      3      3
    (z =) 0      1      2      3      0      1      2      3      0      1      2      3      0      1      2      3

   M = [[[0,     4,     8,    12],    [1,    5,     9,     13]], [[2,    6,    10,    14],   [3,    77,    11,    15], ...]
```

Quite clearly, when `C > 1`, there is some interleaving/skipping going on. For instance, when `C == 2`, `M(1,1,1) == 0`, `M(1,2,1) == 1`, `M(1,1,2) == 2`, etc. But it's not clear to me how the skipping across the values of `C` can be generalised.

Comment: This does not seem related to C++. Also, I would recommend asking this on a math-related SE site! :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more about math than programming